# How to store references to arbitrary entities in RavenDB?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ravendb

I have the need to store arbitrary references to entities within my Raven Database. Sometimes the entity is an aggregate root (see Events below) and other times it is a value entity (see Sessions below). I'm currently planning to store the references as Lucene queries (or a Lucene-like syntax.) Has anyone done anything like this? Am I heading down a difficult path?

Some of my concerns are:

- Value entities are unlikely to provide identifiers, can I expect to reliably reference value entities?
- Individual entities should be unaware of (decoupled from) the Arbitrary Relationship infrastructure, what is the best way to infer the queries from complex object graphs?
- Limiting the relationships to only Aggregate roots (and preventing references to value entities) would simplify the problem, but it would require me to restructure my Event/Session documents. I'd like these two systems to remain decoupled (concerns of one should not impact the other.)

I've included example documents below to illustrate my scenario. Any thoughts, ideas, guidance, or examples would be very appreciated.

```
Events Collection
{
  Id: “30f6...54a7”,
  Title: “Annual Meeting”
  Sessions: [
    { 
      Code: “COM001”, 
      Title: “Opening Ceremony” 
    },
    { 
      Code: “TEC201”, 
      Title: “Intermediate Tech” 
    }
  ]
}

People Collection
{
  Id: "45a8...f209",
  Name: "Chad"
}

Arbitrary Relationships Collection
{
  Id: “b613...8ebb”,
  SubjectEntityQuery: "People.Id:45a8...f209",
  TargetEntityQuery: “Events.Id:30f6...54a7.Sessions,Code:COM001”,
  Action: "Attended Session",
  Story: "Chad attended the Opening Ceremony session"
}
```

**Edit**

I'd like to give more detail on the arbitrary relationships. We will have the ability to extend the system to respond to system events and record the interaction between two entities. We have many more entities than Events, Sessions, and People. The relationship may be a person sharing a link or a tweet about a hashtag. Effectively, the Arbitrary Relationships collection becomes a graph-like structure that allows us to see all ~interactions~ for a given entity.

Answer (score 2):

This is screaming relational design.

The easiest way to do this is make the Relationship an object and its Subject and Target fields an array of strings holding IDs of the actual documents it references. This way you can take advantage of Includes to load them along with the relationship document. Eitherway, I don't see how storing a Lucene query syntax helps here.

There may be a better way to model this, but it really depends on your business model and on the thing you are trying to achieve.

Also, you might want to get rid of GUID IDs, just use Raven's conventions.

Comment: I may or may not actually execute the Lucene query against Raven. What I hope the Lucene syntax buys me is the ability to store the DocumentId (for the aggregate root) and path to the value entity in a single value. I like your suggestion to use Includes.

Re: this screaming relational design - you may be correct, however the core domain of this solution (the events/sessions) fits nicely into the document-oriented paradigm. What does feel relational is the separate concern of wanting track relationship between the arbitrary entities. I'll update the question to give more details that.